# Transfer data from select tag having a foreach loop, in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I know its simple but I am unable to do it.

I have `@foreach` when I have list with my users,(it works) but I need to send the selected user id to another view, yet I always see the id of last user in my database. How I can save the data from loop? by $_POST?

```
<div class="container mt mb-4">
    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
    <h2>Edit </h2>
    <form method="POST" role="form">

        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
        <div>
            <select name="name" id="">
                @foreach($user as $us)
                    <option value="{{$us->id}}" >{{$us->name}} {{$us->lastname}}</option>

                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>


    <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/paneladministratora/editUser/'. $us->id) }}">Edit </a>

    </form>
</div>
```

Now I have in my form, the id of last user but I need the id of the user which is selected.

Thanks.

Comment: add link inside foreach loo, see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hellow, finally i made it.

```
  <h2>Edit </h2>
    <form  method="POST" role="form" >

        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
        <div>

            <select name="name" id="test" onchange="javascript:doUrl(event)">

            @foreach($user as $us1)
                    <option value="{{$us1->id}}">{{$us1->name}}</option>


                @endforeach

                </select>
        </div>


    </form>



        <a id="linkEdit" href="{{ URL::to('admin/paneladministratora/editUser/'. $us1->id) }}">Edytuj3 </a>


</div>

<script>
     function doUrl(e){
        $('#linkEdit').attr('href','/admin/paneladministratora/editUser/'+e.target.value)
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are  accessing $us object outside of foreach loop, that's why it getting only last userId, add link inside foreach loop.

```
<div class="container mt mb-4">
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
<h2>Edit </h2>
<form method="POST" role="form">

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
      @foreach($user as $us)
                $option = '<option value="{{$us->id}}" >{{$us->name}} {{$us->lastname}} 
             </option>';
            <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/paneladministratora/editUser/'. $us->id) }}">Edit </a>
            @endforeach
    <div>
        <select name="name" id="">
            {!! $option !!}
        </select>
    </div>




   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link is outside of the loop. When the loop finishes the variable `$us` will stay with the value of the last user. You need to pass the link to inside of the loop as pointed out in the comments:

```
<select name="name" id="mySelect">
  @foreach($user as $us)
     <option value="{{$us->id}}" >
        {{$us->name}} {{$us->lastname}} 
     </option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

But this approach doesn't make much sense (inserting a link inside of a `<select>` seems... well... weird). I guess you didn't formulate your question correctly and I will assume you would like to show the links to edit every user so you would need to do:

```
@foreach($user as $us)
     <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/paneladministratora/editUser/'. $us->id) }}" id="editLink">Edit </a>
@endforeach
```

**UPDATE**

After OP commented in this answer I understood what he would like to do. 
He would like to have an `Edit` link whenever he clicks on the link and be redirected to the page to edit a certain user.

I'm not sure if there is a pure HTML way to accomplish your goal (at least thinking right now) so you would need to use a little bit of Javascript magic.

You need to listen to changes in `select` and update the link whenever there is a change:

```
<select name="name" id="mySelect">
      @foreach($user as $us)
         <option value="{{$us->id}}" >
            {{$us->name}} {{$us->lastname}} 
         </option>
      @endforeach
</select>

<a href="{{ URL::to('admin/paneladministratora/editUser/'. $us->id) }}" id="editLink">Edit </a>

<script>
  var baseLink = {{ URL::to('admin/paneladministratora/editUser/') }}
  var mySelect;
  window.onload = function() {
    mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    mySelect.addEventListener("change", updateLink);
  }

  function updateLink(){
    document.getElementById("editLink").href = baseLink + mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].value
  }
</script>
```

Not tested right now but you get the idea

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you how to accomplish the goal

Answer (score 0):

When you use '$us->id' outside your foreach, it will give you the value of the last user as that line will be executed after the loop is ended and last value will be stored in that variable. That was the reason u were getting last user's id.

```
   <div class="container mt mb-4">
            @if ($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @endif
            <h2>Edit </h2>
            <form method="POST" role="form">

                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
                <div>
                    <select name="name" id="">
                        @foreach($user as $us)
                            <option value="{{$us->id}}" >{{$us->name}} {{$us->lastname}}</option>
                            <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/paneladministratora/editUser/'. $us->id) }}">Edit </a>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you described in a number of ways, but the best in my opinion, with the least changes to your code, is to submit the form to a URL and retrieve the user ID from the form data, in your controller.

Try this:

```
<div class="container mt mb-4">
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
<h2>Edit </h2>
<form method="POST" role="form">

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
    <div>
        <select name="name" id="">
            @foreach($user as $us)
                <option value="{{$us->id}}" >{{$us->name}} {{$us->lastname}}</option>

            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit"> Edit </button>
</form>
</div>
```